# Basic Linux dmesg questions

Tags: linux, embedded, driver, init, xilinx

and thanks for looking at this question.

I am porting a Linux (2.6.37) driver between bus standards (PLB -> AXI) to be precise for a Xilinx FPGA-SoC. The device driver is compiled inline in the tree. I have a few questions that I am sure you guys can help me.

1. What listing in the Linux kernel tree, allows a device to print the device_*init*_ string on dmesg ? What file is required for the listing ?
2. Normally when a device driver is compiled outside the tree, the extension used (normally) is *.ko, is this the case when the device driver is compiled within the tree and merged using "make modules" ?

***EDITS for Clarity***

Suppose you have a device called "foo", that has to be compiled within the tree. I am observing that "foo" is printing dmesg strings for PLB but not for AXI. I was intending to ask how the device gets added to 'init' ? Which file holds the entry for "foo" that tells init that "foo" has to be loaded ?

For larger sense, foo = xilinx_hwicap

Thanks
RRS

P.S Thanks for your patience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `printk(9)` [prints to the system message ring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036624/where-does-printk-print-to).
2. All modules in 2.6+, regardless of location, end in ".ko".