# Record kernel Log while running an application

Tags: logging, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, printk

I have put some `printk` statement inside Linux kernel like this

```
printk(KERN_DEBUG " Hello from Kernel ");
```

and I am interested to record output of this command while running `a.out` application , like:

```
cp /var/log/dmesg oldLog.txt
./a.out
cp /var/log/dmesg newLog.txt
diff oldLog.txt newLog.txt
```

But it seems this method does not work. Both newLog.txt and oldLog.txt are kind of the same. However, I can observe `"Hello from Kernel"` in `dmesg` command output. Are you aware of an easy way to capture the log like this ?

My second question is about loglevel. I used `KERN_DEBUG` in the `printk` statement but even if I set `echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk` it still print `Hello from kernel` in the `dmesg` command output.

Answer (score 1):

It has been discussed here [Where does printk() print to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036624/where-does-printk-print-to)

`printk` messages will directly go to `dmesg`.

Answer (score 1):

1) printk debug statements always shows up with the dmesg command, does not matter what the loglevel is set. Debug messages can be found in /var/log/messages. 2) Loglevel is set to get the debug messages printed on the console. Even though you set highest priority log level (KERN_EMERG) to print the debug message on the console, it will not not show up in the console if X-server(GUI) is running. For getting the high priority printk messages on the console jump to console mode.